# Xcode 7 auto layout always renders 4:3 ratio

Tags: ios, autolayout, swift2, xcode7

After upgrading my project from Swift 1.2/Xcode 6 to Swift 2.0/Xcode 7 all of my view controllers are rendering in 4:3 ratio (iPhone <=4).  On iPhone <=5 then black space pads the top and the bottom of the screens.

Nothing has changed with the storyboard, and I am not dynamically sizing the views or using any other code to manipulate the view size.

What could be causing this issue, and how to resolve?  I have tried a number of hacks including requesting full screen in the info.plist but cannot get it to work.  It is frustrating since everything worked perfectly before Xcode7.

Below is a screenshot from an iPhone 6 showing the black space above and below the controller.

[image]

Comment: How do your view controllers look on your storyboard? (are they iPhone sized, or are you using Any-Any?)

Comment: Using Any-Any.  Have tried Any-Regular but it had no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it by choosing 'Launch Screen File' as '*.storyboard' from Project Settings -> Targets -> App Icons and Launch Images.

Answer (score 1):

It happens cause you do not have Launch images properly set.

1. Go to image assets
2. Hit + => "App Icons & Launch Images" => "New iOS Launch Image"
3. Now you created a special image asset for launch image. Open it (it has 'LaunchImage' default name) and specify images for all kinds of screen width/height ratios.
4. Also you have to look through project navigator and remove all files that probably exist as launch images (they are named 'Default.PNG', ''Default2X.PNG' or something).

Comment: Thanks - it was launch image that fixed the problem.  Setting the launch screen file to Main.Storyboard was a simpler solution, although your solution is equally valid.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting a workaround: 
If it is an iPhone only app you can simply disable Size Classes from Storyboard: click on view -> enter file inspector (first tab of right panel) and uncheck "Use Size Classes".

Comment: Unfortunately I need both iPhone and iPad. Have tried turning off Size Classes and auto layout and neither have any effect.